# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'io_loop' (When trying to connect to jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, jupyter, local

I have been trying to connect my remote colab file to local jupyter notebook and with reference to the guidance from

```
"https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html"
```

which gave me the rough idea about the process and while solving the issues got through and followed the link

```
"https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html"
```

facing another issue which is:

```
[E 21:14:57.291 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception in /api/kernels/f97bb576-79ba-47ff-ac29-73f66b682344/channels
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 498, in _run_callback
        result = callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\notebook-5.2.2-py3.6.egg\notebook\services\kernels\handlers.py", line 258, in open
        super(ZMQChannelsHandler, self).open()
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\notebook-5.2.2-py3.6.egg\notebook\base\zmqhandlers.py", line 168, in open
        self.send_ping, self.ping_interval, io_loop=loop,
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'io_loop'
[I 21:14:59.587 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel f97bb576-79ba-47ff-ac29-73f66b682344
[E 21:14:59.588 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception in /api/kernels/f97bb576-79ba-47ff-ac29-73f66b682344/channels
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 498, in _run_callback
        result = callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\notebook-5.2.2-py3.6.egg\notebook\services\kernels\handlers.py", line 258, in open
        super(ZMQChannelsHandler, self).open()
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\notebook-5.2.2-py3.6.egg\notebook\base\zmqhandlers.py", line 168, in open
        self.send_ping, self.ping_interval, io_loop=loop,
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'io_loop'
```